# convergence radius of taylor series of a complex function in different directions, the same?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Given the taylor expansion of a complex function`f(z)` around $z_0$, is the convergence radius of this series the same in different directions, say in real axis direction(a real series) and in imaginary axis.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to see that if the Taylor series of $f$ about $z_0$ converges at some point $z$, then it must converge for all points $w$ such that $|w-z_0| < |z - z_0|$. So the radius of convergence is the same in all directions.

This simple argument doesn't tell you anything about convergence *on* the boundary of the disc, which can be complicated: taking $z_0 = 0$ for simplicity, the series might converge at $z = 1$ but not at $z = -1$, e.g. $\sum (-1)^n z^n / n$. But if it converges at $z = 1$ it converges anywhere *inside* the unit disc.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of first part.

Comment: Comment for OP: Note that the terminology is actually correct. The "radius of convergence" is indeed a radius--the radius of the largest open disc centered at $z_0$ on which the series converges.